# Preserve zoom settings in interactive navigation of matplotlib figure

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, tkinter, zooming

Is there a way to preserve the interactive navigation settings of a figure such that the next time the figure is updated the Zoom/Pan characteristics don't go back to the default values? To be more specific, if a zoom in a figure, and then I update the plot, is it possible to make the new figure appear with the same zoom settings of the previous one? I am using Tkinter.

Comment: I found a method called `get_navigate_mode()` but I have no idea how I can use it

Comment: How are you updating the plot? If you're doing it correctly (e.g. `line.set_data`), it does exactly what you want...

Comment: My plot consists of a colormap that I create with `imshow()`. The figure appears when I press a button. For updating I mean pressing the same button again.

Comment: How do you update the image, though? Are you recreating it with `imshow` or are you updating the plot?  (i.e. `im = plt.imshow()` and then `im.set_data(new_data)`)

Comment: The button I used is the same to create the image and to update the plot. If I use `im = plt.imshow()` and then `im.set_data(new_data)` it doesn't keep my navigation panel's settings (it' like it's creating a new figure). I've tried using `imshow` before pressing the button but then I can't use `set_data` and `draw()`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying... If you call `imshow` after or when you "push the button", then you are creating a new plot. What you need to do is update the plot instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I know, I just don't see how I can do it if I'm using the same button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the image instead of making a new image each time.  As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class DummyPlot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.imsize = (10, 10)
        self.data = np.random.random(self.imsize)

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.im = self.ax.imshow(self.data)

        buttonax = self.fig.add_axes([0.45, 0.9, 0.1, 0.075])
        self.button = Button(buttonax, 'Update')
        self.button.on_clicked(self.update)

    def update(self, event):
        self.data += np.random.random(self.imsize) - 0.5
        self.im.set_data(self.data)
        self.im.set_clim([self.data.min(), self.data.max()])
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

p = DummyPlot()
p.show()
```

If you want to plot the data for the first time when you hit "update", one work-around is to plot dummy data first and make it invisible.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class DummyPlot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.imsize = (10, 10)
        self.data = np.random.random(self.imsize)
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

        dummy_data = np.zeros(self.imsize)
        self.im = self.ax.imshow(dummy_data)
        self.im.set_visible(False)

        buttonax = self.fig.add_axes([0.45, 0.9, 0.1, 0.075])
        self.button = Button(buttonax, 'Update')
        self.button.on_clicked(self.update)

    def update(self, event):
        self.im.set_visible(True)
        self.data += np.random.random(self.imsize) - 0.5
        self.im.set_data(self.data)
        self.im.set_clim([self.data.min(), self.data.max()])
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

p = DummyPlot()
p.show()
```

Alternately, you could just turn auto-scaling off, and create a new image each time. This will be significantly slower, though.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class DummyPlot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.imsize = (10, 10)
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

        self.ax.axis([-0.5, self.imsize[1] - 0.5, 
                      self.imsize[0] - 0.5, -0.5])
        self.ax.set_aspect(1.0)
        self.ax.autoscale(False)

        buttonax = self.fig.add_axes([0.45, 0.9, 0.1, 0.075])
        self.button = Button(buttonax, 'Update')
        self.button.on_clicked(self.update)

    def update(self, event):
        self.ax.imshow(np.random.random(self.imsize))
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

p = DummyPlot()
p.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, it's much clearer with an example. My mistake I guess is that I want to be able to both create and update the graph with the same button. In other words, when the programme starts I don't see the graph, which appears when I press a button. The same graph is updated with new data (and sometimes new axis label) after pressing the button once again.

Comment: In that case, you could make an image with dummy data, or make a new image each time but turn autoscaling off.  Have a look at the two new examples. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, that really helps! I think I just have to change the structure of my script. In fact, the figure window is created when I press the button that later on I wanna use to update the graph. In the case you suggested me, the figure window is already created before I press the button, and that's why I wasn't able to use `set_data`. With your solution the plotting will be much faster but the figure window has to be already there when I press the button

Comment: Oh! Well, if you do want a completely new figure window each time (but zoomed to the previous region), you can keep track of the last extent (`extent = ax.axis()`) and then set it when you put up a new figure (`ax.axis(extent)`).  On the other hand, like you say, it's probably better in the long run to change the structure of your code a bit.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably change my structure a bit. Many thanks for your help!